# The WiFi is disabled when I start with Windows and then go back to Ubuntu. A restart is required for WiFi to start

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, windows

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start the PC and in the Grub i select to start with Windows
2. Work in Windows
3. Go back to Ubuntu
4. The WiFi does no start
5. I restart de PC and start with Ubuntu again, then the WiFi start and everything works fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**"Fast Startup" in Windows can cause these types of issues.**

On your Windows install, go thru your power options and disable Fast Startup. This will cause Windows to shut down and boot normally, instead of using the hybrid suspend.