# Unclaimed Network Controller on Ubuntu 23.04 HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-eb0xxx

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, iwlwifi

## Problem

I recently tried dual booting my **HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-eb0xxx** machine with *Windows 11* and *Ubuntu 23.04*. Unfortunately, the Ubuntu system is never able to connect to the internet via it's wifi card. Wifi works as expected when running Windows 11.

Windows 11 device manager reports my wifi card is an Intel Ax201 160MhZ device.

I have obtained the following diagnostic information:

### dmesg

```
[    2.352442] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'd0i3_disable' ignored
[    2.352445] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'lar_disable' ignored
[    2.354883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.368115] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Can find a correct rfid for crf id 0x617
[    2.368163] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

### sudo lshw -C network

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:606311c000-606311ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 15
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: enxa0cec8645734
       serial: a0:ce:c8:64:57:34
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.46 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

### uname -r

```
6.2.0-26-generic
```

### lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

### lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 06fc
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
38:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
6d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5405
6e:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

## I have tried:

- The following dual boot permutations:

  - Ubuntu 18.04 + Windows 10
  - Ubuntu 18.04 + Windows 11
  - Ubuntu 20.04 + Windows 11
  - Ubuntu 22.04 + Windows 11
  - Ubuntu 22.04 + Windows 10
  - Ubuntu 23.o4 + Windows 10

> Across all permutations
>
> - wifi *always* works on windows.
> - wifi *never* works on Ubuntu
> - Bluetooth* occasionally / intermittently* works on Ubuntu.

- Disabling Fast Boot on the Windows control panel power settings, as described here: [The WiFi is disabled when I start with Windows and then go back to Ubuntu. A restart is required for WiFi to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254608/the-wifi-is-disabled-when-i-start-with-windows-and-then-go-back-to-ubuntu-a-res)
- Disabling Secure Boot on my BIOS.
- Patching my network drivers as described here: [Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 is not working on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04)
- EDIT: Reinstalling `linux-modules-extra` as described by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474267/1721042)
- EDIT: Removing `linux-modules-*-iwlwifi` and installing `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` as described by [this bug report](https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg503049.html)
- EDIT: Manually installing `sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9904-0ubuntu5_all.deb` from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/) and firmware from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) with `sudo tar -zxvf linux-firmware-20230804.tar.gz -C /lib/firmware`, as described by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1363582/1721042)

> Note: Between each attempted fix, Ubuntu 23.04 was reinstalled to unpersist and changes made.

## Wireless Script Output

```
########## wireless info START ##########
 
Report from: -
 
Booted last: -
 
Script from: -
 
##### release ###########################
 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
 
##### kernel ############################
 
Linux 6.2.0-26-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 10 23:39:54 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, pcie_aspm=force, vt.handoff=7
 
##### desktop ###########################
 
Ubuntu
 
##### lspci #############################
 
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:06f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:0000]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
 
##### lsusb #############################
 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 
##### PCMCIA card info ##################
 
##### rfkill ############################
 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 
##### secure boot #######################
 
SecureBoot disabled
 
##### lsmod #############################
 
hp_wmi                 24576  0
platform_profile       16384  1 hp_wmi
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
iwlwifi_compat         16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 hp_wmi,intel_hid
wmi                    40960  5 hp_wmi,video,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi
 
##### interfaces ########################
 
##### ifconfig ##########################
 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.46/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
       valid_lft 86261sec preferred_lft 86261sec
    inet6 2404:4404:2a05:6500:e6c7:405c:2b2a:3be5/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 463sec preferred_lft 463sec
    inet6 2404:4404:2a05:6500:9654:cb46:8e32:6a4c/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 463sec preferred_lft 463sec
    inet6 fe80::909:f8fe:5b19:e95/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 
##### iwconfig ##########################
 
lo        no wireless extensions.
 
enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.
 
##### route #############################
 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto dhcp src 192.168.1.46 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.46 metric 100 
 
##### resolv.conf #######################
 
[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']
 
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
 
##### network managers ##################
 
Installed:
 
    NetworkManager
 
Running:
 
root         895       1  0 11:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 
##### NetworkManager info ###############
 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8152
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 v1.12.13
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       fe10c681-3252-36c4-a1c9-4f3a0302b388
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.46/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1691717581
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.46
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2404:4404:2a05:6500:e6c7:405c:2b2a:3be5/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2404:4404:2a05:6500:9654:cb46:8e32:6a4c/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::909:f8fe:5b19:e95/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::9ec9:ebff:fe24:cc12
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2404:4404:2a05:6500::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::9ec9:ebff:fe24:cc12, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::9ac9:ebff:fe24:cc12
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 00:04:47:4c:de:bd:34:80:1b:f7:86:ef:3d:20:dd:03:56:2a
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::9ac9:ebff:fe24:cc12
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        iaid = f2:b2:1f:c2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   fe10c681-3252-36c4-a1c9-4f3a0302b388 | Wired connection 1
 
##### NetworkManager.state ##############
 
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
 
##### NetworkManager config #############
 
[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
 
[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
 
##### NetworkManager profiles ###########
 
##### Netplan config ####################
 
[/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
 
[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
 
##### iw reg get ########################
 
'iw' is not installed (package "iw").
 
##### iwlist channels ###################
 
lo        no frequency information.
 
enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no frequency information.
 
##### iwlist scan #######################
 
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
 
enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.
 
##### module infos ######################
 
[iwlwifi_compat]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/iwlwifi-compat.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Kernel backport module
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           iwlwifi_compat
vermagic:       6.2.0-26-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           backported_kernel_name:The kernel tree name that was used for this backport (iwlwifi) (charp)
parm:           backports_tracker_id:The version of the tree containing this backport (iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9904:0e80336f) (charp)
 
##### module parameters #################
 
grep: /sys/module/iwlwifi_compat/parameters/backported_kernel_name: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/iwlwifi_compat/parameters/backports_tracker_id: Permission denied
[iwlwifi_compat]
 
##### /etc/modules ######################
 
##### modprobe options ##################
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/iwl.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=0 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1 
options iwlwifi d0i3_disable=1 
options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1 
options iwlwifi lar_disable=1
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
 
##### rc.local ##########################
 
grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory
 
##### pm-utils ##########################
 
##### udev rules ########################
 
##### dmesg #############################
 
[    4.787935] r8152 1-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: carrier on (repeated 2 times)
[ 6503.122088] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready
[ 6503.122411] r8152 1-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: carrier on
 
########## wireless info END ############
```

*None of my attempted fixes seem to have any effect whatsoever. Am stumbling around in the dark here - would appreciate any suggestions :)*

Comment: Does this help? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/q/425155/1684306)

Comment: I ran the script and uploaded the info here: https://pastebin.com/BtXUcfxt

Comment: Output of `rfkill list all` is not listing your wireless device. Also, `lspci` in the script output shows that the kernel module for this device is `iflwifi`, but it's not indicating that it's in use. That's why it's unclaimed: driver isn't binding to it. Therefore, it appears that the `iflwifi` driver installed doesn't cover this device. The device code is `06f0`, so if you run `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 06f0`, it'll probably show no results. At this point, the solution is a bit out of my wheelhouse, but hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @mpboden. Indeed `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 06f0` shows nothing.

Comment: Perhaps the `backport-iwlfifi` driver might help: [Backport for iwlwifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046589/backport-for-iwlwifi). Also, more driver info at [Intel](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi). And I found this info at [Hardware For Linux](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-06f0-8086-0000)

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions. I have tried manually installing the drivers for Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (5.2) (from your intel link above) by copying their contents to `/lib/firmware` with no luck. Are there additional key steps I must perform to install this firmware?

Comment: I tried installing the `backport-iwlfifi` driver per the link you provided. This altered the `dmesg` output slightly ```sudo dmesg | grep wifi
[    8.865897] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    8.865899] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:11368:aee7e2b4
[    8.975376] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.979626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id 0x20000302 wfpm id 0x0
[    8.979647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Can't find a correct rfid for crf id 0x617
[    8.979660] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22```

Comment: I found [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg503049.html) bug report for the Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 failing after upgrade to 23.04. Their solution was: “removed all the existing linux-modules\*iwlwifi\* 
packages then installed backport-iwlwifi-dkms and it worked”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147822/discussion-between-student-a-and-mpboden).

Answer (score 0):

Long stort short, I bought one of these:

https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/tl-wn725n/

Would still really like to know the software fix, though.

Comment: Four months on and I still haven’t found a solution. If anyone has some tips they’d be super appreciated!