Ubuntu 22.04 wifi button disappeared and failed to use wireless network
I have an issue after installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my Lenovo Legion laptop. The wifi button disappeared and I can't connect to the internet using wifi. I used the command sudo lshw -c network and have the line "Network Unclaimed".
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b4518000-b451bfff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 15
   serial: 98:fa:9b:ed:24:c4
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.60 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4304000-b4304fff memory:b4300000-b4303fff

After using the command [sudo dmesg | grep iwl], here are the complete error messages.
[    3.184712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0xa5a5a5a2, cnv-id 0xa5a5a5a2 wfpm id 0xa5a5a5a2
[    3.184727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Can't find a correct rfid for crf id 0x5a2
[    3.184744] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22

wireless info:
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 26 Aug 2024 23:14 CDT -0500

Booted last: 26 Aug 2024 00:00 CDT -0500

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:0000]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38cd]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:c100 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8910)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6488064  0
iwlwifi               598016  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
wmi_bmof               12288  0
cfg80211             1327104  2 wl,iwlwifi
ideapad_laptop         57344  0
sparse_keymap          12288  1 ideapad_laptop
platform_profile       12288  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  73728  2 ideapad_laptop,nvidia_modeset
wmi                    28672  4 video,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.60/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp7s0
       valid_lft 43027sec preferred_lft 43027sec
    inet6 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::1dd7/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86227sec preferred_lft 86227sec
    inet6 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0:2bcf:baa5:9627:3637/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86228sec preferred_lft 86155sec
    inet6 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0:d54f:e606:fb59:378b/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86228sec preferred_lft 86228sec
    inet6 fe80::24c8:790f:df17:bc2a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp7s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.60 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         621       1  0 23:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp7s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-40-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.5/0000:07:00.0/net/enp7s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:07:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp7s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       0a534e93-f980-38b8-9f2f-fbb77e889e99
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.60/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name = lan
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1724775094
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = tianwei-Legion-Y540-17IRH
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.60
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2600:6c44:11f0:13f0:2bcf:baa5:9627:3637/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::1dd7/128
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         2600:6c44:11f0:13f0:d54f:e606:fb59:378b/64
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         fe80::24c8:790f:df17:bc2a/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::7637:5fff:fe3a:5754
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::/60, nh = fe80::7637:5fff:fe3a:5754, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::1dd7/128, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::7637:5fff:fe3a:5754, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::1
IP6.SEARCHES[1]:                        lan
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = lan
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        fqdn_fqdn = tianwei-Legion-Y540-17IRH
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        ip6_address = 2600:6c44:11f0:13f0::1dd7
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   0a534e93-f980-38b8-9f2f-fbb77e889e99 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp7s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp7s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       6.8.0-40-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       6.8.0-40-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:0:disable, 1-15:FW_DBG_PRESET Values, 16:enabled without preset value defined,Debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 16) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11be:Disable EHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-40-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
disable_11be: N
enable_ini: 16
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0.conf]
blacklist gspca_kinect

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.100902] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file intel/ibt-17-0-0.sfi (-2)
[    6.398056] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: Link is Down
[    9.095022] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx

########## wireless info END ############


This question is similar to: My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your details imply you've used very outdated media from mid-2022; why not use updated media?  (ie. 22.04.4 is the current media; with 22.04.5 being tested currently).

@waltinator Thanks for your reply! I followed this post and the complete information is right here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gGHw8Fc74r/ please let me know what to do next.

this is very similar to a problem I've been having https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481793
